# How do you call the action when you select items in a checkbox?

Tags: checkboxes

This is more of an English language question, but UX designers will readily understand.
When i have a checkbox with items, then say for a help description text, do you rather use the verb "*select items*" or "*check items*"?

I have also the case where the user has made another choice elsewhere and i need to pre-select items (in a checkbox) as a result of that other choice. And there is a user action to trigger that selection.

Would you rather say "*Select items based on [other choice]*" or "*Check items based on [other choice]*"?

"*Select*" seems more natural to me and "*check*" sounds like "*verify*" which is not the intent.
But then it is called "*checkbox*" for a reason?
As you could have guessed, I'm not a native English speaker.
Can someone clarify and confirm?

Comment: You should use a different word for your “checkbox”, it is very confusing as it is already commonly used for a single item: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox

Answer (score 4):

Select will do just fine. Most users will understand what this means.
Even though we (UX/dev type people) all know it's called a checkbox, the users may not.

To avoid confusion I'd recommend sticking with the most well know phrase that covers this behavior as you have mentioned - **Select**

Another alternative you may want to consider is **choose**

Comment: The original GUI terminology for both Windows and Mac proclaimed that choose is only for things that cause immediate action -- you "choose" a menu command, you "select" and "clear" a check box.

Answer (score 2):

### Microsoft

> #### **Documentation**
>
> When referring to check boxes:
>
> - Use the exact label text, including its capitalization, but don't
>   include the access key underscore or colon. Include the word check
>   box.
> - Refer to a check box as a check box, not option, checkbox, or just
>   box, because box alone is ambiguous for localizers.
> - To describe user interaction, use select and clear.
> - When possible, format the label using bold text. Otherwise, put the
>   label in quotation marks only if required to prevent confusion.
>
> Example:
> Select the **Underline** check box.

[Microsoft Docs - Check Boxes # Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-check-boxes#documentation)

---

### Apple

Checkbox is "selected" or "deselected"

[Human Interface Guidelines for macOS - Checkboxes](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/toggles/#Checkboxes)

---

### Google

Checkbox is "selected" or "unselected"

[Material Design - Checkboxes](https://m2.material.io/components/selection-controls#checkboxes)